# Javascript regexp match

Tags: javascript, replace, match

Hi all I'm trying to get all the digits of a class that contains several nodes... just want to get the numbers of 10 digits. I'm very tangled I hope someone helps me.
* I would also like to know if in a single long text extract all matches found and not just one

```
var lista = document.querySelectorAll(".dat");
for(i in lista){
    if(lista[i].textContent.match(/.*([0-9]{10}).*/, $1)){
        console.log(lista[i].textContent + "\n") 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: pls is code :) I just want to get all the number of each iteration would have to use the global ' G ' flag do not know if you can help me.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your `.dat` elements?

Comment: There are many span labels

<span>text text 2345438943 text text</span>
<span> 2345438943 text  text</span>
<span> text  text  text 2345438943 </span>

Comment: <span class="dat">text 9023548932</span>
        <span class="dat">9023548932 text text</span>
        <span class="dat">text text 9023548932</span>
        <span class="dat">te 9023548932 xt</span>
        <span class="dat">tex 9023548932 text text</span> ONLY NUMBERS

Comment: (By the way, it is customary to [minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your example code.) Try entering this expression on the JavaScript console:  `"text 01234 text 0123456789 text 9876543210 text".match(/\d{10}/g)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work? `.match` returns an array if a match was found. The first item in the array is the matched string, then every other item is each capture group. So your number capture group would be in the 1st position:

```js
var lista = document.querySelectorAll(".dat");
for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    var match = lista[i].textContent.match(/.*([0-9]{10}).*/);
    if (match && match[1]) console.log(match[1]);
}
```

```html
<span class="dat">text 9023548932</span>
<span class="dat">9023548932 text text</span>
<span class="dat">text text 9023548932</span>
<span class="dat">te 9023548932 xt</span>
<span class="dat">tex 9023548932 text text</span>
```

Comment: Okey Thank you very much "CRice" I was missing the array of matches, continue studying.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/\d{10}/` and check for item `0` in the array instead of item `1`:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dat")).forEach(item => {
    var match = item.textContent.match(/\d{10}/);
    if (match && match[0]) console.log(match[0]);
})
```

```html
<span class="dat">text 9023548932</span>
<span class="dat">9023548932 text text</span>
<span class="dat">text text 9023548932</span>
<span class="dat">te 9023548932 xt</span>
<span class="dat">tex 9023548932 text text</span>
```